# How do I stop Firebase from creating an additional nested object or how can I access the newly generated string?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem**: Whenever I add an order to the **orders** array, an additional nested array element(**-KOPWA...**) gets added. I wouldn't mind except, I don't know how to access that nested string to access it's child nodes.

Example of database node for users below:

[image]

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+userIdState+'/orders/'+<<unique numbervariable>>).push({
  "order":{"test":"product","quantity":2}
});
```

I'm using the above code to push new json objects with a unique number to the firebase array. Still the nested array with the weird strings gets generated.

**Can anyone help me understand how to either:** create my own nested array with my own unique string or how to access the nested string that gets generated from firebase so I can access it's children nodes. 
Multiple instances of nest arrays will be generated by users.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Moe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're experiencing this behaviour because Firebase's `push` is not the same as an array `push`. I recommend reading [this article](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push) to understand how it works.

As for a solution, you can simply change `push` to `set` in your code. This will create the structure you were (presumably) expecting, that is

```
1:
  order:
    ...
```

This is however potentially unsafe, if you allow concurrent writes (i. e.  if the "unique number" in your example is not always unique).

Afaik Firebase recommends using `push` to safely create collections/"arrays". You can retrieve the generated key by calling the `key` property on the reference returned by `push`. Like this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/'+userIdState+'/orders/'+<<unique numbervariable>>).push({
  "order":{"test":"product","quantity":2}
});
var generatedKey = ref.key; // the value you're looking for
```

If you decide to use it, you can probably just drop the order number you have right now and just use the generated one.

Comment: Thanks heaps.

I tried your method verbatim and I'm getting a "Uncaught TypeError: ref.key is not a function". Any idea why?

Comment: I made a mistake. `key` is.a property, not a function.